# Create index with expression on PostgreSQL to find non-zero values

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I'm trying to create an optimized, partial index to find all rows where the numeric field `amount` is not zero.

This

```
CREATE INDEX amount_not_zero_idx ON my_table (amount)
WHERE amount <> 0;
```

is working, but it's not really what I have in mind as only the information "unlike zero" is important. What I would like to do is something like

```
CREATE INDEX amount_not_zero_idx ON my_table (amount <> 0)
WHERE amount <> 0;
```

as this should give the best performance - but PostgreSQL gives a syntax for the "<>" error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Found it myself. Problem was simply missing brackets, correct syntax is

```
CREATE INDEX amount_not_zero_idx ON my_table ((amount <> 0))
WHERE amount <> 0;
```

Comment: I typically include the PK columns in a partial index so that it can be used for lookups.